# Navigation compose deprecated backQueue

Tags: android, navigation-compose

I updated the `androidx.navigation:navigation-compose` from version 2.5.3 to 2.7.4 and I get the error:`Cannot access 'backQueue': it is private in 'NavController'`

```
private fun NavOptionsBuilder.clearBackStack(navController: NavController) {
  var firstEntry: String? = null

  // first element can be null, we are search for the first non-null one
  for (entry in navController.backQueue) {
    val route = entry.destination.route
    if (route != null) {
      firstEntry = route
      break
    }
  }
  firstEntry ?: return

  popUpTo(firstEntry) {
    inclusive = true
  }
}
```

How to do the same thing without the `backQueue`?

Comment: The `NavHost` lets you define a route for your root graph (what will always be the first element in the back stack) - the only reason it is  null is because you didn't define it as something other than null. Is there a reason you don't override that parameter? Then your `popUpTo` always has a fixed value right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an explanation of why backQueue is [private](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217465473):

Source Code for `NavController.kt`

```
private val backQueue: ArrayDeque<NavBackStackEntry> = ArrayDeque()
```

You are trying to access a `private` value.

I cannot offer an alternative suggestion because the relevant API was never intended to be [public](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/217465473#comment6). There are comments to this effect.

Maybe `currentBackStackEntry` will do the trick.